# How to bind Dynamic property name or Column in AngularJs 1.0 Html expression

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am facing one problem while binding data to angularJs 1.0.

I have fetch the data from the Database via a Pivot Query with Dynamic Column name,

but I did not able to bind data to angularJs html expression ,

can any one here to suggest me how I can achieve this. my Data is look like below.

```
[{"5V00L":"Charcoal","T200":"No Color","GradeName":"Pre Kindergarten","GradeLevelId":10},{"5V00L":"Sapphire","T200":"Heather Grey & Red","GradeName":"Kindergarten","GradeLevelId":11},{"5V00L":"No Color","T200":"Gold & Navy","GradeName":"1st Grade","GradeLevelId":14},{"5V00L":"No Color","T200":"White & Lime Shock","GradeName":"Grade-Name","GradeLevelId":27}]
```

in this **5V00L** and **T200** is the dynamic column name.
So please help me how I can bind these two column property in my angulrJs html expression Like **object.GradeName**

Comment: Are you sure that these two dynamic properties are going to be the first and second property?

Comment: @Shubhranshu Yes, first 2 property will be the dynamic property.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = { 5V00L: "Charcoal", T200: "No Color", GradeName: "Pre Kindergarten", GradeLevelId: 10};

var firstDynamicVal = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]];
var secondDynamicVal = obj[Object.keys(obj)[1]];
console.log("First Value: "+firstDynamicVal+", Second Value: "+secondDynamicVal);
```

you can try this to get the first two value. But this solution will work only when the order of the property remains same.

Comment: How I can bind this data in ng-repeat in html expression.my final object list is 
[{"5V00L":"Charcoal","T200":"No Color","GradeName":"Pre Kindergarten","GradeLevelId":10},{"5V00L":"Sapphire","T200":"Heather Grey & Red","GradeName":"Kindergarten","GradeLevelId":11},{"5V00L":"No Color","T200":"Gold & Navy","GradeName":"1st Grade","GradeLevelId":14},{"5V00L":"No Color","T200":"White & Lime Shock","GradeName":"Grade-Name","GradeLevelId":27}]

Answer (score 1):

After spend 2-3 hours top resolve this I found the below way to.
My list of object was:

```
 [{"5V00L":"Charcoal","T200":"No Color","GradeName":"Pre Kindergarten","GradeLevelId":10},{"5V00L":"Sapphire","T200":"Heather Grey & Red","GradeName":"Kindergarten","GradeLevelId":11},{"5V00L":"No Color","T200":"Gold & Navy","GradeName":"1st Grade","GradeLevelId":14},{"5V00L":"No Color","T200":"White & Lime Shock","GradeName":"Grade-Name","GradeLevelId":27}]
```

**5V00L** and **T200** was two first dynamic property.
Create a angular function.

```
  $scope.ObjectKey = function (obj) {
         return Object.keys(obj);
     }
```

I have used this function in my html like below:

```
 <div  ng-repeat="color in Colors">
                    <div style="width: 33%; float: left">
                        {{color[ObjectKey(color)[0]]}}
                    </div >

                    <div style="width: 33%; float: left">
                        {{color[ObjectKey(color)[1]]}}
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [ECMAScript Third Edition (pdf)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered
>   collection** of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.

which means that you can't be sure that your custom properties would have 0 and 1 indexes.

Instead of hoping that they would always be the first, a better way would be to list all properties with `ng-repeat` loop and hide those which are predefined.

HTML:

```
   <div ng-repeat="item in list">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
        <p ng-hide="!isCustomProperty(key)">
          <b ng-bind="key"></b>: <span ng-bind="value"></span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var predefinedProperties = ['GradeName', 'GradeLevelId'];

$scope.isCustomProperty = function (prop) {
    return predefinedProperties.indexOf(prop) < 0;
};
```

Here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thesameson/hw9okfzr/) with working example

**UPDATE**

And even a better solution would be to store your dynamic properties as an array of objects.

For example:

```
[{
    "GradeName":"Pre Kindergarten",
    "GradeLevelId":10,
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "key": "5V00L",
            "value": "Charcoal"
        }, {
            "key": "T200",
            "value": "No Color"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "GradeName":"Kindergarten",
    "GradeLevelId":11,
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "key": "5V00L",
            "value": "Sapphire"
        }, {
            "key": "T200",
            "value": "Heather Grey & Red"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "GradeName":"1st Grade",
    "GradeLevelId":14,
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "key": "5V00L",
            "value": "No Color"
        }, {
            "key": "T200",
            "value": "Gold & Navy"
        }
    ]
}, {
    "GradeName":"Grade-Name",
    "GradeLevelId":27,
    "Attributes": [
        {
            "key": "5V00L",
            "value": "No Color"
        }, {
            "key": "T200",
            "value": "White & Lime Shock"
        }
    ]
}];
```